# Selenium - Text entered into text field disappears

Tags: selenium-webdriver, textbox

I am working on Selenium Python Automation.
I am using Javascript instead as well where needed.

I am clicking a button and a sub-page appears which has text input fields:
I am entering the text through below code:

```
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('<javascriptpath>.value='Test'")
```

The test is getting entered into the text box.

But, when the 'Search' button is clicked through the next piece of code, it returns all search results, instead of returning the results matching with the 'search text' entered in the text box in the previous step.
It means the text entered through `value='Test'` is not getting picked up.

How can I enter the value into the text box which will be retained by the field?

[image]

Comment: Can you share the URL of the application if it is public?

Comment: sorry it is internal so cannot share.